# Custom CMS, adding new Documents don't appear until IIS is Reset

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

We've built 2 applications using MVC, and Administrative and Client app.  The admin side is used to create and update XML files that have page content.  The client Application merely reads the XML and displays it as html.

The XML files are hosted on a shared drive and both applications read the files from the same location so that the data was decoupled from the apps.

Content Updates made to any files appear immediately on the client application but any NEW files that are created with the Admin app do not appear until IIS is recycled on the client app.

```
    string p = string.Format("{0}{1}", SiteInfo.Instance.SitePath, @"\sitemap.xml");
    var model = new Models.Pages.PagesPageModel
    {
        CMSPage = Models.Entities.CMSPage.EntireList(p)
    };

   private static List<CMSPage> EntireList(string path)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

        var list = new List<CMSPage>();
        var all = doc.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name == "page").ToList();
        //var all = doc.Element("webpages").Elements().Where(d => d.Name == "page").ToList();
        foreach (var p in all)
        {
            var page = GetPage(p);

            //recursion for children
            page.Children = GetChildrenPages(page, p);

            list.Add(page);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

There must be a way to get the apps to refresh to files list without resetting IIS everytime?

Comment: In my opinion, you should firstly find out how and when the CMS generate the html page according to XML file. I guess the gernerated html page method is called when the application started. You could copy the codes inside the method and create a new method according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the List was being stored in a static variable.